# What is the JavaScript equivalent of PHP's sprintf function?

Tags: javascript, php, math

Here is my PHP code:

```
$kg= 75.20283619791667;
$lbs = sprintf("%.1f",$kg*2.20462);
// $lbs should equal 165.8
```

What is the equivalent in JavaScript if I start with:

```
var kg=75.20283619791667;
var lbs=2.20462*kg;
```

And I want to end with `165.8` as in the PHP example.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: There's no native function such as `sprintf`. However, [there's a project](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js) that tries to implement it. Quite ironically, had you googled it, that's what you'd have gotten :)

Comment: @SethBattin that works you should make it an answer

Comment: Naw, other people need the rep more than I do.  I'm sure someone will pick it up.  :)

Comment: @SethBattin ok well thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box equivalent for sprintf in javascript. But there are already some libraries which implemented this function on their own.
For example you could have a look at: https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js